# J2EE EJB3 webservice for image generation

Tags: jakarta-ee, io, ejb, awt

I need an advice for the best solution on how to make a web service which returns a generated image. For instance client gives yard id and service depending on business data generates the image of the yard (that's just an example). 
So I am using EJB3 and JPA to accomplish this. There's no problem reading data from datasource and exposing ejb as a web service. But I am worried about two things - using AWT in ejb and file I/O in ejb.

1. **AWT in EJB?**

   I've created BufferedImage and I am using java.awt.Graphics2D to draw the image - lines, circles etc.. I am not drawing anything to screen, just to BufferedImage which I am willing to pass back to client. 
   So the question is - is this a good idea to do that? If not what would be the best solution? 
   It is said that "The program violates the Enterprise JavaBeans specification by using AWT/Swing." So is it really bad idea to use awt in this situation? 
   Also it is said that "An enterprise bean must not use the AWT functionality to attempt to output information to a display, or to input information from a keyboard." Does that mean AWT could be used in different situations (like this as I"m not displaying anything on screen)?
2. **File I/O in EJB?**

   I can't use i/o for external files, but what about files that ar located in my ejb jar file? Is it possible for read only data to be stored in deployment jar file?
   For instance I have small pattern files which I want to read and use for my drawing (decorating rectangle background etc.).
   So would it be appropriate to put them in my jar file and use them only for reading?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The program violates the Enterprise
>   JavaBeans specification by using
>   AWT/Swing

This is only when you are using AWT/Swing for interacting with the Keyboard/mouse. You are creating a buffered image. I do not see any problems with this.

BTW, are you planning to pass on the buffered image back to the client? Wouldn't A *real* image, some `jpg` or `png` be better?

> File I/O in EJB?

File IO in EJB *is* considered bad. But for your situation, since you are reading some patterns, these are actually resource bundles. You can use [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29%27) or [ClasLoader.getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to read the configuration files (which are in a jar, for instance)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Nivas!
Yes, I'm planning to pass back the png image not the buffered image. Response will be SOAP message with attachment (my generated image).